# iCalendar exclude date range

Tags: php, calendar, export, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am working on school timetables system and currently developing a PHP script that would allow exporting the data in iCalendar (.ics) format. The target use-case of exporting the data would be importing it into Google Calendar.

Since there are holidays inbetween the semesters in our school (specified by start and end date), **what would be the best way to exclude the holidays from the iCalendar recurrence rule (`RRULE`)?**. Keep in mind that there can be many different schedules in one export.

I did try using `EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:YYYYMMDD,YYYYMMDD,YYYYMMDD...` with all holiday days, but Google Calendar didn't exclude the dates, probably because schedules also have time attached and therefore they don't match.

I'll also provide the data in iCalendar format with one of the events, with holiday days excluded one by one (the one that didn't work)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Gregor Eesmaa/NONSGML Poska timetables//ET
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:schedule-1442@jpg.tartu.ee
SUMMARY:French
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:Room 210
DTSTART:20151215T123000Z
DTEND:20151215T134500Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20160211;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU
EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20151223,20151224,20151225,20151226,20151227,20151228,20151229,20151230,20151231,20160101,20160102,20160103,20160104,20160105,20160106,20160107,20160108,20160109,20160110,20160319,20160320,20160321,20160322,20160323,20160324,20160325,20160326,20160327,20160415,20160416,20160417,20160418,20160607,20160608,20160609,20160610,20160611,20160612,20160613,20160614,20160615,20160616,20160617,20160618,20160619,20160620,20160621,20160622,20160623,20160624,20160625,20160626,20160627,20160628,20160629,20160630,20160701,20160702,20160703,20160704,20160705,20160706,20160707,20160708,20160709,20160710,20160711,20160712,20160713,20160714,20160715,20160716,20160717,20160718,20160719,20160720,20160721,20160722,20160723,20160724,20160725,20160726,20160727,20160728,20160729,20160730,20160731,20160801,20160802,20160803,20160804,20160805,20160806,20160807,20160808,20160809,20160810,20160811,20160812,20160813,20160814,20160815,20160816,20160817,20160818,20160819,20160820,20160821,20160822,20160823,20160824,20160825,20160826,20160827,20160828,20160829,20160830,20160831
LAST-MODIFIED:20160102T123758Z
DTSTAMP:20160107T232137Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing wrong.  I would recommend creating a simpler iCal file that you can use for testing purposes, just to figure out how to do it right.  Then, once you get it working for a simple example, apply what you learned to the real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question looking for a solution that would exclude whole ranges. After careful consideration, I decided to do this properly, by excluding only the date-times where the event would actually take place. This decreased the file size of the export three fold.

I also added timezone information as recommended for using `RRULE`. Now the French lesson event would look like this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:schedule-1442@jpg.tartu.ee
SUMMARY:French
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:Room 210
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Tallinn:20151215T143000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Tallinn:20151215T154500
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20160211;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=TU
EXDATE;TZID=Europe/Tallinn:20151229T143000,20160105T143000
CREATED:20160102T123758Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20160102T123758Z
DTSTAMP:20160108T115122Z
END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 1):

If DTSTART is a date-time value then EXDATEs must also be date-times. I propose you append T123000Z to each of your EXDATEs to make them actually point to valid instance starts. They will then get correctly excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this other [SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391677/how-to-exclude-a-particular-date-while-creating-a-recurring-event-in-ical-outloo), it seems you're not setting any excluded date in `EXDATE`. `EXDATE` can be set to `DATE`, based on the [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1) specificaiton.

Based on the answer on the other issue, your `EXDATE` should have been

```
EXDATE:20151223,20151224,20151225,20151226,20151227,20151228,20151229,20151230,20151231,20160101,20160102,20160103,20160104,20160105,20160106,20160107,20160108,20160109,20160110,20160319,20160320,20160321,20160322,20160323,20160324,20160325,20160326,20160327,20160415,20160416,20160417,20160418,20160607,20160608,20160609,20160610,20160611,20160612,20160613,20160614,20160615,20160616,20160617,20160618,20160619,20160620,20160621,20160622,20160623,20160624,20160625,20160626,20160627,20160628,20160629,20160630,20160701,20160702,20160703,20160704,20160705,20160706,20160707,20160708,20160709,20160710,20160711,20160712,20160713,20160714,20160715,20160716,20160717,20160718,20160719,20160720,20160721,20160722,20160723,20160724,20160725,20160726,20160727,20160728,20160729,20160730,20160731,20160801,20160802,20160803,20160804,20160805,20160806,20160807,20160808,20160809,20160810,20160811,20160812,20160813,20160814,20160815,20160816,20160817,20160818,20160819,20160820,20160821,20160822,20160823,20160824,20160825,20160826,20160827,20160828,20160829,20160830,20160831
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: According to the specification, my formatting is correct, as specified: `exdate = "EXDATE" exdtparam ":" exdtval *("," exdtval) CRLF`, where `exdtparam = ...(";" "VALUE" "=" ("DATE-TIME" / "DATE"))...`. Also, your suggestion didn't keep Google Calendar from showing the schedules on holidays.